# C array of pointers and malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to get data from std stored into an array, using pointers. The main declares d as `int *d;` and the function is called using `x = getdata(&d);` When I step through it with gdb it dies at the first iteration of the for loop, when it tries *d[i]=val;

```
int getdata(int **d)
{ 
    int count,val,i,j=0; 

    scanf("%d", &count);

    d = malloc(sizeof *d * count);
    for( i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {

    scanf("%d",val);

    *d[i]=val;  

    }

    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++)
            printf("Number %d\n",*d[i]);

    return count;
```

}

Comment: Say `*d = malloc(sizeof **d * count);`, and `(*d)[i]`.

Comment: Maybe he wants `(*d)[i]` ?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &val);` BTW: a serious compiler should warn you about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory should be allocated as follows

```
*d = malloc(count * sizeof **d);
```

The values should be accessed as follows

```
(*d)[i] = val;
```

It is also not clear why you allocate `count` elements and only initialize `count - 1` elements in the input cycle (and later print all `count` elements in output cycle).

Comment: thanks, it was this and me forgetting the `&` in `scanf("%d",&val)` !

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers.

1) `malloc` returns a void* so you need to assign the result to `*d` instead of `d`

2) the data size you want is of an `int`, not an `int*` (using `*d` gets you an `int*` where `**d` is an int)

```
*d = malloc(sizeof(**d) * count);
```

3) Indexing the array requires slightly different syntax

```
(*d)[i] = val;

printf("%d\n", (*d)[i]);
```

4) The second scanf needs a pointer, not an int

```
scanf("%d", &val);
```

Comment: `*d = malloc(count * sizeof **d );` is more robust than sizeof *type* .

Comment: I agree with this.  Edited

Comment: you don't need the parentheses with `sizeof expression` (that's why I put "count" in front)

Comment: I'm still getting a segmentation fault

Comment: I missed the &val on your second scanf.

Answer (score 2):

```
*d = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
```

then

```
(*d)[i] = val
```